# Reading X axis from i2c library with a HMC5883L

Tags: python, i2c

I using a HMC5883L with the i2c library. I am using this code to get the direction it is facing

```
from i2clibraries import i2c_hmc5883l

hmc5883l = i2c_hmc5883l.i2c_hmc5883l(1)
hmc5883l.setContinuousMode()
hmc5883l.setDeclination(0,6)
print(hmc5883l)
```

But this prints all of the axises and I just want the x-axis but I do not know how just get the x-axis alone so I can compare x values. If anyone knows how to do this your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a Pi specific question.  Assign hmc58831 to a variable and use standard Python functions to extract the information you want.  Search for Python tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

you can find sample code for [HMC5883 over here](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/HMC5883).

here you will find c,java,python and micro python code.
just to get X axis look at this section.

xMag = data[0] * 256 + data[1]
if xMag > 32767 :
    xMag -= 65536

zMag = data[2] * 256 + data[3]
if zMag > 32767 :
    zMag -= 65536

yMag = data[4] * 256 + data[5]
if yMag > 32767 :
    yMag -= 65536

So all you need to do is, read the first 16bit.